# Units of mean decrease accuracy on a variable importance plot obtained from a Random Forests classifier?

Tags: machine-learning, r, random-forest

To know the importance variable in a Random Forest I used The mean decrease accuracy and mean decrease Gini.

I would like to understand what are the x-axis units of the mean decrease accuracy and mean decrease Gini on a variable importance plot obtained from a random forests classifier. For example the mean decrease accuracy and gini values range between 0,000 - 0,012 and 0-600 respectively.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Please give more details, we can't answer without any context.

Comment: I shared my plots. Mean decrease accuracy and mean decrease gini are used to know the variables importance in a RF but i don't understand the x-axis. What is the meaning of this values? How can I interpreter?

Comment: Logically the mean decrease accuracy must be by how much the accuracy decreases when training the model without the feature. But if you want a detailed answer you should explain why you are using these measures, what is the task etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Gini decrease** is calculated based on the mean decrease in Gini i.e. $p_i(i-p_i)$ each time when the Tree is splitted on that Feature. Value is so high because the r package weight the impurities by the raw counts, not the proportions.

**Accuracy decrease** is calculated on OOB dataset by randomly shuffling the data for that particular feature in the OOB. Then subtracting the two accuracies i.e. before and after shuffling.

**Unit** -

Accuracy - Unitless - Ratio of correct classification to total records

Gini impurity - Unitless - Measurement of the cleanliness of split.[Formal](https://bambielli.com/til/2017-10-29-gini-impurity/#gini-impurity)

These links have got good detail:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55055245/2187625)

[r-bloggers](https://www.r-bloggers.com/be-aware-of-bias-in-rf-variable-importance-metrics/)

[Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-do-you-explain-%E2%80%98mean-decrease-accuracy%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98mean-decrease-gini%E2%80%99-in-layman%E2%80%99s-terms)